# Is it possible to download an app not available in my country? What about buy it?

Tags: store

An aggregated question I know but...

Sometimes developers choose to publish their app for some specific market instead of make globally available.

In this case you will be presented with an advice in the Store saying you can't install that particular app.

Is it possible to bypass this check? And if I can bypass I will be eligible to buy it too?

I will give an example of a free app:

[Easy Taxi](http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/easy-taxi/81abe749-907d-4950-ae38-f6e5a689155d) (link to Brazilian Store)

As far as I know this app is only available in 9 countries but **USA** is not the case.

If you try to access with an American phone you will see this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your phone's country settings should work:

> The location of Store is based on your phone's Country/Regional
>   settings. To change the location:
>
> 1. Go to Settings > Language+region and then select Country/Region.
> 2. Tap Restart phone button.
> 3. The new Store settings will become effective after the phone has been rebooted.

Source: http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA137731

Comment: What about buying an app in a country different from mine?

Comment: @VitorCanova you can't :/ I had to buy a prepaid gift visa card from the US to buy the apps from the US market.

Comment: So @HaLaBi it is possible since I have an eligible payment option for that country?

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem I faced was the address. If the address for the credit card does not match the one in the DB it will be declined. Because WP forced me to choose an address in USA when I changed the market to USA in settings.

Comment: @HaLaBi Probably Microsoft gift cards are the solution. You just need to buy one from the same country of the app.

Comment: It might be a long-shot, but you could also consider emailing the developer and asking them to release it worldwide. In your example such a thing might make sense e.g. if I was visiting Brazil I might want to download Brazilian apps before arriving.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different method there if you want a free app. I don't know about the payment in case of paid apps.

You have to go to windowsphone.com and install app from there. The URL you have given here is http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/easy-taxi/81abe749-907d-4950-ae38-f6e5a689155d. If you couldn't find any install button then the URL is not for your location. But you can change the URL to fit your location.

From the URL you can identify the language and country abbreviations. Here it is **pt-br**, (the hierarchy after the windowsphone.com domain name). Edit this in the URL, for example my location is India and for me, I have to change it to **en-in** That is your '**language abbreviation-country-abbreviation**'. If your location is US then change it to **en-us**. Then you will get the install button.

PS: Link to  find your 2 letter [country abbreviation](http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm) 
Link find the 2 letter [language abbreviation](http://www.science.co.il/Language/Codes.asp)

Comment: The problem is: if the app is not published in one specific market it will not show the install button. It will say that the app in not available in the country. In my case I sent them an email and it became available.